# modify my navbar in media queries. Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i´m  trying to modify my navbar across media queries, for medium and large screens my logo it´s into a jumbotron div, but i want to change where it appears when the screens is less than 768px, i want to put it on my navbar. Can I make it on my css or not.

Thanx.

This is my code for md and lg screens.

```
 <!-- Jumbotron
```

================================================== -->

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img/iconos/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 login">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" id="btnlogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Entrar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <!-- Navbar
```

================================================== -->

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WORKSHOPS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MAESTROS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ESCAPADAS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EQUIPAMIENTO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="socialicons">
                        <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/face-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
                        <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/gplus-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
                        <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/tube-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>           
                    </ul>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: But you didnt told us how do you like to look??

Comment: My navbar is under the jumbotron, and the logo for md and lg screens its in jumbotro. I want to put the logo img in the navbar (collapse) for the small screens

Comment: Have you look my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">


 <div class="col-md-6 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <img src="img/iconos/logo.png">
            </div>


<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">WORKSHOPS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MAESTROS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ESCAPADAS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">EQUIPAMIENTO</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="socialicons">
                            <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/face-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/gplus-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/iconos/tube-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>           
                        </ul>

            </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. i´ve just to fit the logo now in the nav because it move the collapse icon. But this solution it´s so good, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS3 to design different layouts for different screen widths, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

In order to achieve what you are asking, consider hiding the logo from the Jumbotron by default, and only showing it when the min-width of the screen exceeds a certain amount. For example, your CSS might look like this:

```
.my-logo {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .my-logo {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

You can then use this same logic to show/hide the logo from the navbar.

Comment: In Bootsrap 3 there is class for hide and show element :) You dont need to add new media queries just add class

Comment: Fair enough. They may need to write their own CSS if they want more flexibility than Bootstrap's helper classes provide, but if they simply need to hide/show at the pre-defined widths, your suggestion works well.